# What is the best way to tell if a character is a letter or number in Java without using regexes?

Tags: java, char, numbers, letter

What is the best and/or easiest way to recognize if a string.charAt(index) is an A-z letter or a number in Java without using regular expressions? Thanks.

Answer (score 379, accepted):

`Character.isDigit(string.charAt(index))` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))) will return true if it's a digit
`Character.isLetter(string.charAt(index))` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char))) will return true if it's a letter

Comment: Note: that these tell you if the character is a Unicode letter / digit.  The OP asked for "an A-z letter" ... whatever that means.

Comment: Why does the ASCII ├ (255 ) pass in my case? I thought its for a-z, A-Z and 0-9 only?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Links are now fixed. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Use`Character.isLetterOrDigit(string.charAt(index))` for both the verifications.

Comment: Be careful, isLetterOrDigit gives true on way more than a-Z0-9 !!!  refer to the doc here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)

Answer (score 38):

I'm looking for a function that checks only if it's one of the Latin letters or a decimal number. Since `char c = 255`, which in printable version is **├** and considered as a letter by `Character.isLetter(c)`.
This function I think is what most developers are looking for:

```
private static boolean isLetterOrDigit(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ||
           (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ||
           (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}
```

Comment: Just went through our code and was amazed how many bugs were in there because of isLetter and isLetterOrDigit... Thank you!

Comment: Somehow you have gotten your character-sets and or display fonts mixed up.  Unicode codepoint `u00ff` is actually the character ÿ.  (Lower-case y with an umlaut.)  The codepoint that represents ├ is `u251c`.

Comment: @StephenC you're right. I forgot how I end up typing that character instead of [nbsp](https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/non-breaking-space-no-break-space-ascii-code-255.html)

Comment: On Kotlin it is much simpler `if (c in 'a'..'z' || с in 'A'..'Z' || c in '0'..'9')`

Answer (score 31):

As the answers indicate (if you examine them carefully!), your question is ambiguous.  What do you mean by "an A-z letter" or a digit?

- If you want to know if a character is a **Unicode** letter or digit, then use the `Character.isLetter` and `Character.isDigit` methods.
- If you want to know if a character is an **ASCII** letter or digit, then the best thing to do is to test by comparing with the character ranges 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z' and '0' to '9'.

Note that all ASCII letters / digits are Unicode letters / digits ... but there are many Unicode letters / digits characters that are not ASCII.  For example, accented letters, cyrillic, sanskrit, ...

---

The general solution is to do this:

```
Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.of(someCodePoint);
```

and then test to see if the block is one of the ones that you are interested in.  In some cases you will need to test for multiple blocks.  For example, there are (at least) 4 code blocks for Cyrillic characters and 7 for Latin.  The `Character.UnicodeBlock` class defines static constants for well-known blocks; see the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html).

Note that any code point will be in **at most** one block.

Answer (score 17):

Java Character class has an [isLetterOrDigit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)) method since version 1.0.2

Comment: Be careful, isLetterOrDigit gives true on way more than a-Z0-9 !!!  refer to the doc here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)

Answer (score 12):

I don't know about best, but this seems pretty simple to me:

```
Character.isDigit(str.charAt(index))
Character.isLetter(str.charAt(index))
```

Comment: Be careful, isLetterOrDigit gives true on way more than a-Z0-9 !!!  refer to the doc here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)

Answer (score 9):

Use the below code

`Character.isLetterOrDigit(string.charAt(index))`

Comment: What does your answer add that hasn't been covered in the previous answers?

Comment: Be careful, isLetterOrDigit gives true on way more than a-Z0-9 !!!  refer to the doc here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)

Comment: Robert, instead of calling two functions you can of course just call one function.

Answer (score 8):

```
// check if ch is a letter
if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
    // ...

// check if ch is a digit
if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    // ...

// check if ch is a whitespace
if ((ch == ' ') || (ch =='\n') || (ch == '\t'))
    // ...
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/charintro.html

Comment: The preceding code is wrong because it works only with English and a few other languages. To internationalize the previous example, replace it with the following statements:        char ch;
// ...

// This code is OK!

if (Character.isLetter(ch))
    // ...

if (Character.isDigit(ch))
    // ...

if (Character.isSpaceChar(ch))
    // ...

Comment: OP clearly asked `if a string.charAt(index) is an A-z letter`. So we are not talking about other languages are we ?

Comment: In e.g., German, an ä could be considered to be in the a-z range.

Answer (score 5):

Compare its value. It should be between the value of 'a' and 'z', 'A' and 'Z', '0' and '9'

Comment: This manual approach is better than the built-in `Character.isLetter()` method?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - It depends precisely what you are trying to do.  Hint: they do different things!

Comment: @StephenC I thought `Character.isLetter()` is rudimentary.  Unless we are talking about internationalization?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - Read the javadocs.  Then check the Unicode specs for what code-points the respective character classes actually contain.  >>Of course<< we are talking about internationalization.  Characters in Java are all Unicode based.

Comment: how do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class v{
 public static void main(String args[]){
 Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    int l;
    int flag=0;
    System.out.println("Enter the String:");
    str=in.nextLine();
    str=str.toLowerCase();
    str=str.replaceAll("\\s","");
    char[] ch=str.toCharArray();
    l=str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        if ((ch[i] >= 'a' && ch[i]<= 'z') || (ch[i] >= 'A' && ch[i] <= 'Z')){
        flag=0;
        }
        else

        flag++;
        break;
        } 
if(flag==0)
    System.out.println("Onlt char");


}
}
```