# Is it possible to use Integer.parse for String array of "mixed" types?

Tags: java

I have a String array

```
String[] list = new String[]{"2","A","B","1","C","3","D","E","F"}
```

Please Note that the first element of array is 2.
I would have done -

`int n = Integer.parseInt(list[0]);`

Problem is, I need a loop to go through the array. I cant seem to parse it without giving me a `NumberFormatException` error. Also, notice that if the number is a 2, it will arrange the next 2 elements (might be random) and then a space.

> 1: A
>
> 2: B
>
> 3: -empty-
>
> 4: D
>
> 5: E
>
> 6: F
>
> 7: -empty-
>
> 8: C

Comment: Can't you `try` it and then do something else with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to check to see if a String represents an integer in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-to-see-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java)

Comment: Blindly you can't do it.  Why would you even do it ? As your problem statement says, converting whole to array to integer doesn't seem your purpose.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the number in the array specifies the number of elements that are string following in the array and retrieve the string elements only?

Comment: @aurora_titanium please post a reply to my previous comment as a new comment if you require help

Comment: You don't have to face NFE if you first read digits then read digits many characters without converting them to integer. Control is in your hands so you can definitely avoid NFE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm is simple enough.

- Parse number
- Shift N values 1 position to the left
- Assign empty value to vacant space
- Advance past block, and repeat

Progress is a follows:

```
Start: "2","A","B","1","C","3","D","E","F"
N = 2
Shift: "A","B","B","1","C","3","D","E","F"
Empty: "A","B","-","1","C","3","D","E","F"
N = 1
Shift: "A","B","-","C","C","3","D","E","F"
Empty: "A","B","-","C","-","3","D","E","F"
N = 3
Shift: "A","B","-","C","-","D","E","F","F"
Empty: "A","B","-","C","-","D","E","F","-"
```

*Code*

```
String[] list = {"2","A","B","1","C","3","D","E","F"};
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ) {
    int len = Integer.parseInt(list[i]);
    System.arraycopy(list, i + 1, list, i, len);
    list[i + len] = "-empty-";
    i += len + 1;
}
for (String value : list)
    System.out.println(value);
```

*Output*

```
A
B
-empty-
C
-empty-
D
E
F
-empty-
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for explaining the solution. I am new to Java. How do you improve problem solving skills or algorithm? Where can I practice this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array and check whether the selected character is a digit or not. If it's a digit use parseInt.

Here's a tutorial on how to identify digits. [What is the best way to tell if a character is a letter or number in Java without using regexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047808/what-is-the-best-way-to-tell-if-a-character-is-a-letter-or-number-in-java-withou)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try/catch statement in your loop when you iterate over the array.

Here's a short example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    try {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(list[i]);
        // do whatever you need to do with n here
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfex) {
        // do something else with the current element if need be
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String hexNbr : list) 
{
   System.out.println("Next number is " + Integer.parseInt(hexNbr, 16);
}
```

Your input is hex, so you have to use parseInt(String, radix).