# java check if char is number in switch case statment

Tags: java, switch-statement, isnumeric

I have a switch case that checking if char is "=" or "-" or "+"
but I like to check also if char is a number from 0-9

```java
    public static Token get(char ch) {
            switch (ch) {
                case '-' :
                case '+':
                case '=':
                    return new Token(ch);
                case  Character.isDigit(ch): // this dosn't work
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

what can I replace the Character.isDigit with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to tell if a character is a letter or number in Java without using regexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047808/what-is-the-best-way-to-tell-if-a-character-is-a-letter-or-number-in-java-withou)

Answer (score 2):

You could define explicit `case` statements for the ten digit characters:

```java
public static Token get(char ch) {
    switch (ch) {
        case '-' :
        case '+':
        case '=':
            return new Token(ch);
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            // handle digit case
            break;
    }
}
```

Note here that we simply let all digit characters cases flow into a single point for handling.

Answer (score 1):

This would not work, since a switch case compares your `char ch` variable to the switch cases to get a match. `Character.isDigit(ch):` returns a boolean value, which cannot be directly compared to `char ch`.

I would suggest an alternate approach where you check for your condition in the default case.

```java
public static Token get(char ch) {
    switch (ch) {
        case '-' :
        case '+':
        case '=':
            return new Token(ch);
        default:
        if(Character.isDigit(ch){
            //enter code here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers are correct and good. I would add two points:

- Using a `switch` statement for your logic may be clouding the intent rather than clarifying it. Using a series of `if-then` in your particular case may make more sense.
- The `char` type in Java is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode. While the use of `char` in this particular code will work, I suggest you not make a habit of using `char`. Instead, learn to use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead.

You can easily determine the code point.

```java
String input = "";
int codePoint = input.codePointAt( 0 );
```

> 128567

Call [`Character.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)) to get a `String` object containing a single character, the character represented by that particular code point integer number.

Example code.

```java
public class Token
{
    public static Token get ( int codePoint )
    {
        if ( "-+=".contains( Character.toString( codePoint ) ) )
        {
            // Do operator stuff.
            return new OperatorToken( codePoint );
        } else if ( Character.isDigit( codePoint ) )
        {
            // Do digit stuff.
            return new DigitToken( codePoint );
        } else
        {
            // Do default stuff.
            return new DefaultToken( codePoint );
        }
    }
}
```